# How to run 'go test' and include unit test files but exclude other test files

Tags: unit-testing, go

I'm trying to automate running unit tests on an existing Go project. It already has a lot of existing tests which do non-unit test things like contact external services and write to databases. I would like to exclude these test files from the automation using a naming convention. Say the structure of the project is like this:

```
gopath/
|-package1.go
|-package1_unit_test.go
|-package1_e2e_test.go
|-package2/
  |-package2.go
  |-package2_unit_test.go
  |-package2_e2e_test.go
```

I can run `go test ./...` to run all the tests. If I include 'UnitTest' in the names of my unit tests I can run `go test ./... -run UnitTest` but this still runs the startup code in the e2e tests. I need it to completely ignore those files. Someone suggested running `go test $(go list ./... | grep -v /e2e/)` but `go list` outputs directory names, not file names, so that doesn't work.

And yes, ideally the e2e tests should go in a different directory and not rely on the internals of the package but unfortunately that's not how my coworkers wrote them. I'm looking for a quick fix right now!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use build tags to limit builds, including tests, to a certain subset of files: https://dave.cheney.net/2014/09/28/using-build-to-switch-between-debug-and-release

For example, you could put `//+build integration` at the top of your integration test files, and then those would only be built and executed when you run `go test -tags integration`.